# OpenLayers 2 / MapServer: Limited zoom levels

Tags: openlayers-2, mapserver, zoom

I want to display a MapServer raster image with OpenLayers 2. My problem is that I cannot zoom into the image although the resolution should allow it.

This is what I have so far:
http://geocre.net/mapservertest/

A detail of the original image:

[image]

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<title>OpenLayers MapServer Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/theme/default/style.css" media="all" />
<style>
html { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; }
body { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; font-family:sans-serif; }
#map { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script>
// set projection:
var projData = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var projDisplay = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

// initialize map:
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', { projection:projDisplay, controls:[new OpenLayers.Control.Zoom(), new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({'zoomWheelEnabled':true}), new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine()] } );

// set basemap:
var rasterLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer("Tamale (wet season)", "http://78.47.251.2/cgi-bin/mapserv", {map:'/mapserver/tamale_ws.map'});
map.addLayer(rasterLayer);

// set map center:
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat( -0.83945,9.3833).transform(projData, projDisplay), 15);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

MapServer map file:

```
MAP
  IMAGETYPE      JPEG
  EXTENT         -94018 1048833 -92362 1049470
  SIZE           1000 400

  WEB
    METADATA
      "wms_title" "mymap"
      "wms_srs" "epsg:900913"
    END
  END

  LAYER

    METADATA
      "wms_title" "mymap"
      "wms_srs" "epsg:900913"
      "wms_enable_request" "*"
    END

    NAME         myraster
    DATA         /mapserver/data/tamale_wet_season.tif
    STATUS       DEFAULT
    TYPE         RASTER
    PROCESSING   "BANDS=1,2,3"
    OFFSITE      0 0 0
  END 
END
```

Comment: If you don't show the code you have so far you probably won't get any answers.

Comment: I linked HTML file.

Comment: There is something odd with the MapServer configuration. It can't respond to WMS requests. Do you have the line `"wms_enable_request" "GetMap GetCapabilities"` in the `METADATA` section of your mapfile?

Comment: I just added it, here is my map file: http://geocre.net/mapservertest/tamale_ws.map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the fixed mapfile, it become clear to me, this is a client side problem. There is nothing wrong with the MapServer setup, the resolution limit has been set in the OpenLayers `map` object automatically. To override this limit, include a `maxResolution` parameter in your `OpenLayers.Map` constructor.

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', { 
    projection:projDisplay, 
    controls:[
        new OpenLayers.Control.Zoom(), 
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({'zoomWheelEnabled':true}), 
        new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine()
    ], 
    maxResolution: 500 
});
```

Adjust the default zoom level corresponding with the new resolutions.

```
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat( -0.83945,9.3833).transform(projData, projDisplay), 8);
```

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/GFarkas/ank15g68/1/

Note: the 500 px `maxResolution` value is just an estimate. Take your time to play with it, until it fully satisfies your needs.